# Initializing React number input control with blank value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like my controlled input to initialize with no value in the box. 
The input is a number, so I don't pass in an empty `''`.
Using defaultProps, I initialize the input with a null.

When typing into the input the console reports this message:

*`<MyInput>` is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).*

To prevent this normally I initialize with an empty string to prevent this "switching" from happening. But with a number (I don't want to show a 0, I want nothing to show) I am not sure how to do it.

```
static defaultProps = {
    estimatedHours: null,
    estimatedMinutes: null,
  }
```

defalut values ^^

```
<input
   type="number"
   onChange={(e) => this.handleChange('Hours', e.target.value)}
   onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
   onPaste={this.handlePaste}
   value={estimatedHours}
   placeholder={hoursText}
   className="slds-input th-trailmix-textbox th-time-component__input"
/>
```

Comment: Can you share the uncontrolled input component code?

Comment: Can't seem to replicate this? Which version of React are you using?

Comment: Using React 15.6.1

Comment: Use `defaultValue` and `onBlur` combination.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uncontrolled inputs are simply inputs where you aren't tying `value` to JavaScript. So if you are rendering:

```
<input value={any} />
```

That is a controlled input.

If you want to render an uncontrolled input with an empty value you could simply write

```
<input type="number" /> or <input type="number" placeholder="" />
or <input type="number" placeholder="please enter a number..." />
```

Next, if you want to pull the value use a ref.

```
state = {
  query: ''
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ query: this.search.value })
}

render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        ref={input => this.search = input} 
        placeholder="" 
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Additionally, you can still perform logic on the return value if you need to. ie:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ query: this.search.value.toExponential(2) })
   // square whatever the user inputs and store in this.state.query
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I want a controlled number input with a null / undefined initial value.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? In your original post you stated you wanted your _un_controlled input to initialize with no initial value. Setting the `type` attribute to "number" accomplishes it being a number input.

Comment: A value is passed into component X as props via Redux. Component X has a number input that uses that value. The initial value should be empty. The value should be validated as type number via propTypes

Comment: How do you want the input to use the value? Are you trying to compare what is passed to component X with what the user actually enters? If so, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Sage911/4abe73fcddebf57ae8f69db6d5a06fc7). Hope that makes sense. Let me know if this helps and I will edit my original answer.

Answer (score 16):

Simpler approach is to have a fallback value be an empty string.
Works for `type=number` as well.

```
<input type="number" value={estimatedHours || ''} />
```

Comment: Note that if `estimatedHours` is `0`, it'll fallback to the empty string. To avoid this, either use the ternary operator or use the nullish coalescing operator https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing.

Comment: +1 for the comment on using nullish coalescing operator since if a value starts as either `null` _or_ `undefined` you get the warning about a uncontrolled input switching to controlled. Thus the following works nicely: `value={estimatedHours ?? ''}`

Answer (score 3):

You can set value Undefined,

Also add a check for input type if required

```
class Input extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: undefined};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const isnum = /^\d+$/.test(event.target.value);
        if (isnum) {
            return this.setState({
                value: Number(event.target.value),
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="number"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={String(this.state.value)}
                placeholder={"Please enter number"}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

and convert String to Number and vice versa

This won't throw you an error for uncontrolled input

Comment: The key being the string conversion of the input value attribute. It will fail without that.

Comment: This works, but I get a warning `The specified value "undefined" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.` from React in the console.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like my controlled input to initialize with no value in the box.

> my problem is that I want a controlled number input with a null /
> undefined initial value.

I suggest defaulting the value props in the input element with an empty string like the following:

```
<input
   type="number"
   // ...
   value={estimatedHours === undefined ? '' : estimatedHours}
/>
```

This will make the input empty and prevent the warning from React. It'll also conveniently work well with the `required` prop too so the user must enter an input.

In TypeScript 3.7+, it can be shorted to the following using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing):

```
<input
   type="number"
   // ...
   value={estimatedHours ?? ''}
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to get the behaviour you are looking for is to define the prop type for this field to a `string`. This will allow `''` to be used as a default prop. On form submission, you will need to make sure that the value of this field is parsed to a number.

```js
type FormProps = {
  estimatedHours: string;
  estimatedMinutes: string;
}

FormProps.defaultProps = {
  estimatedHours: '',
  estimatedMinutes: '',
}
```