# Initializing controlled React input with blank value and type="number"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Problem:**

I have a controlled input, using Material-UI TextField. I want to have purely numbers, and support type="number" for mobile keyboards, but when having empty string as default, and having a parseInt in the `onChange`, it will not allow 0 (zero). All other numbers are displayed correctly.

It even correctly sets 0 in the underlying object bound to the TextField.

In other inputs i have default values as empty strings (heavily simplified), like shown:

```js
<TextField
    name={"inputToBeSaved"}
    value={this.state.objectForSaving.inputToBeSaved|| ''}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    variant="outlined"
/>
```

With corresponding handleChange:

```js
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        objectForSaving: {
            ...prevState.objectForSaving,
            [name]: value
        }
    }))
}
```

The example above works as espected, but not when trying to work with numbers:

```js
<TextField
    type="number"
    name={"numberToBeSaved"}
    value={this.state.objectForSaving.numberToBeSaved|| ''}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    variant="outlined"
/>
```

```js
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.type === 'number' ? parseInt(target.value) : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        objectForSaving: {
            ...prevState.objectForSaving,
            [name]: value
        }
    }))
}
```

I know that defaulting to 0, or making it uncontrolled will fix it, but some times I do have values there from the server, so I want to reuse the components.

I have tried to look at this post, but did not find any good solution to keep it controlled: [Initializing React number input control with blank value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642449/initializing-react-number-input-control-with-blank-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is falsey, so in the following condition:

```
this.state.objectForSaving.numberToBeSaved|| ''
```

if `numberToBeSaved` is 0, then the expression will evaluate to empty string.

If you are just trying to check if `numberToBeSaved` is defined, then you can do this more robustly with:

```
this.state.objectForSaving.numberToBeSaved === undefined ? '' : this.state.objectForSaving.numberToBeSaved
```

Comment: That was a perfect explanation. I testet a little and made a isUndefined helper-method. That solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you happen to already be using lodash, you could use its `isUndefined` or `isNil` functions rather than duplicating these kind of helper methods in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to string when setting the `TextField` prop.

```
const {
  objectForSaving: {
    inputToBeSaved = '',
  },
} = this.state

<TextField
  name={"inputToBeSaved"}
  value={String(inputToBeSaved)}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if using formik, do it like this:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      inputToBeSaved: "",
      ...
    },
  });

  <TextField
    id="inputToBeSaved"
    name="inputToBeSaved"
    type={"number"}
    {...formik.getFieldProps("inputToBeSaved")}
    label={"input To Be Saved"}
    variant="outlined"
  />
```